# how to render Thymeleaf data inside dynamically calling JQuery function?

Tags: jquery, html, thymeleaf

```
$("#addPreparationProcessList").on("click", function () {

    var index = $("#preparationProcessList").find("textarea").length;

    var elementToAdd = '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-8"><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><span class="input-group-addon"  th:placeholder="#{placeholder.whatiscooking_placeholder}"></span>' +
        '<textarea type="text" style="height:80px;" id="preparationProcessList' + index + '.preparationProcess" class="form-control top_margin_small"  
th:placeholder="#{placeholder.whatiscooking_placeholder}" 
placeholder="What is Cooking"></textarea> </div> </div>';

    $("#preparationProcessList").append(elementToAdd);
});
```

This is the example code we are calling this JQuery function in ui page so text area will be added to html page.

Here th:attributes are not resolving to labels or placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the placeholders to resolve, you need to change your code to :

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

  //whatever else you have

                $("#addPreparationProcessList").on("click", function () {

                    var whatIsCookingPlaceholder = /*[[#{placeholder.whatiscooking_placeholder}]]*/ 'test';

                    var index = $("#preparationProcessList").find("textarea").length;

                    var elementToAdd = '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-8"><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><span class="input-group-addon" placeholder="' + whatIsCookingPlaceholder + '"></span>' +
                            '<textarea type="text" style="height:80px;" id="preparationProcessList' + index + '.preparationProcess" class="form-control top_margin_small"' +
                    'placeholder="' + whatIsCookingPlaceholder + '"></textarea> </div> </div>';

                    $("#preparationProcessList").append(elementToAdd);
                });
</script>
```

Check out [this](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart) part of the documentation for more information

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I need to resolve the thymeleaf tag, when i call the function, or i want to get it from .properties file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean you need to resolve the Thymeleaf tag? From what I see from your code you are using `th:placeholder` in order to set the placeholder dynamically. That syntax won't work inside Javascript. You need to use the `/*[[#{placeholder.whatiscooking_placeholder}]]*/` construct that I have shown above